# Проблема с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

В файле такие настройки:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|styles|js|css|font|.jpg|.woff|.ttf|.svg|.eot|otf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

В корне сайта лежит файл html, и мне нужно на него перейти name.com.ua/name.html
Но этого я сделать не могу, так понимаю, из-за этой строчки:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Что нужно добавить, чтоб я мог открывать html файлы с корня движка сайта, но чтоб и прежние свойства сохранились?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|styles|js|css|font|.jpg|.woff|.ttf|.svg|.eot|otf|.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Нет, не работает! Работает, только если я уберу строчку RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]